# Parsing HTML Span element having id

Tags: php, html-parsing, html

I am showing a snippet of HTML code I was working on.I want to extract the value of the element under the span having an ID coveredAreaUnit but no classname.
I was able to access span elements having classnames through HTML DOM parsing
$html->find('span.classname').
I tried for span elements having some id as 
$html->find('span#idname')
but this doesn't work.

I also tried $html->find(#idname) but that doesn't help either
I can access this span element in another way(i.e. by using DOM tree elements and nodes) but that is way too ugly.

Snippet

```
    ......
<span id="coveredAreaUnit" style="display:none;">Sq-ft</span>
<span id="coveredArea" style="display:none;">1350</span>
    ........
```

Comment: why don't you give them IDs?
and then use document.getElementById("");

Comment: I'm fetching data in PHP from a third party website through CURL. I can't manipulate their data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
document.getElementById("coveredAreaUnit").innerText;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("coveredAreaUnit").innerHTML;
```

Comment: What u said was a Javascript code.Anyways works when modified into PHP.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)?

If so you can use:

```
$html->find('span[id=coveredAreaUnit]');
```

Comment: Not working. I feel somehow that display:none property of these spans are making these commands not work.

Comment: Is Simple HTML DOM what you are using? I don't believe the styles should affect the parsing, unless the data is being manipulated by Javascript when you view it normally.

Comment: The commands $html->find('span#id'),('span[id=]')&('#id') didn't work. I just thought that display:none was affecting them.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not parse with `id`s yet , using span indexes.
Might be of some help to you:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html('<span id="coveredAreaUnit">Sq-ft</span><span id="coveredArea">1350</span>');
$res1 = $html->find('span',0); 
$res2 = $html->find('span',1); 
echo $res1;
echo $res2;
```